# Create a BAT that can open a selection of executables?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file that gives me a selection to open various executables. For example,

```
What do you want to open?
1. Application1.exe
2. Application2.exe
3. Application3.exe
```

Inputting a number will open the desired executable that isn't in the same directory as the batch file itself. So it's basically a launcher.

Comment: "I want to make a batch file" Feel free to do so! And have a look on the [tour] to learn how this site works. This is a duplicate, not researched at all and does not show any attempt of you to find a solution to this problem!

Comment: What a community.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a community! This is the concept of the site you are using; you show effort, you get help. You show no effort (and not even read the tour tage) you get no help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
:input
    echo What do you want to open?
    echo 1. Application1.exe
    echo 2. Application2.exe
    echo 3. Application3.exe
    set /p "app=: "
    if "%app%"=="1" goto :start Application1.exe
    if "%app%"=="2" goto :start Application2.exe
    if "%app%"=="3" goto :start Application3.exe
    echo Invalid option!
goto :input
:start
    start "" "%~1"
exit
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @SamDenty If at all in 7 minutes ;) And in addition to that, he did not do so for the last question he asked and the other one has been a duplicate as well as this one.